# How to pass an Array between two sibilings in react

Tags: reactjs

In my project I have App.js that is Parent component. And for Parent component there are two child components those are Childone component and Childtwo component. Now I am trying to pass data from Childone component to Childtwo component. Someone please tell me to achieve this

This is App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import Childone from "./Childone/Childone";
import Childtwo from "./Childtwo/Childtwo";

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Childone />
        <Childtwo />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is Childone

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Childone extends Component {
  render() {
    const Employs = ["Mark", "Tom"];
    return <div className="Childone" />;
  }
}

export default Childone;
```

This is Childtwo

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class Childtwo extends Component {
  render() {
    return <div className="Childtwo" />;
  }
}

export default Childtwo;
```

If you feel I am not clear with my doubt, please put a comment.

Comment: As ehutchllew suggested, use a container that contains ChildOne and ChildTwo. ChildOne sets a value through a callback that was passed by the container (useState). The container then passes down that value to ChildTwo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways of doing it.

1. By passing data from **Childone** to **Parent** through callback and from **Parent** to **Childtwo** as prop. Thereby letting parent be the intermediatory.
2. By creating a context at the parent and let **Childone** be the **producer** and **Childtwo** be the **consumer**.

Context is used to avoid prop drilling. Also frequent update of context values isn't considered as a good practice.
Also, for your case we can go with approach ( 1 ).

You can enter data in Childone and see the data reflect in Childtwo in  [this sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/share-data-between-siblings-in-react-nozmu).

Answer (score 0):

Are you familiar with React's unidirectional data flow? I would try to create a mental model in your head of having the `Parent` be the container/controller that passes the required information into your children.

So in this case you would either want the data to originate from `Parent` or have some event handler associated with the data in `Child1`. If the latter, attach a callback function from `Parent` to `Child1` that accepts the data as an argument to then be passed into `Child2`.

Answer (score 0):

best solution is is to use redux. If you are not familiar  with  redux then you can follow below approach :

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import "./style.css";

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      number:[0] 
    };
  }

  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <div>Parent Componet</div>
        <Child1 passToChild={this.passToChild.bind(this)}> </Child1>
        <Child2 number={this.state.number}></Child2>
      </div>
    )
  }

  passToChild(number){
    this.setState({
      number : [...this.state.number,number]
    });
  }
}

class Child1 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div>Child1</div>
        <button onClick={() => this.sendToSibiling()}>
          Send data to sibiling
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }

  sendToSibiling() {
    this.props.passToChild(Math.random());
  }
}
class Child2 extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <div>Child 2</div>
        <span>data from sibiling : {...this.props.number}</span>
      </div>

    )
  }
}
```

Comment: I would disagree. Redux for such a trivial example is unnecessary.